# WPF ScrollViewer show border when ScrollBar is Visible

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, scrollviewer

I want to add a border to my ScrollViewer. The border should only be shown when the ScrollBar of the ScrollViewer is Visible (VerticalScrollBarVisibility set to "Auto")

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Binding` and `Converter`.

```
public sealed class VisibilityToBorderThicknessConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var flag = (Visibility)value;
            if (flag == Visibility.Visible)
                return new Thickness(0);
            else
                return new Thickness(1);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new Thickness(0);
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and than your xaml:

```
 <ScrollViewer Name="blah">
      <Border BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=blah, Path=VerticalScrollBarVisibility , Converter={StaticResources VisibilityToBorder}}">
 </ScrollViewer>
```

don't forget to add your converter to resources!

GL&HF

Comment: It doesn't work. I the reason is, the VerticalScrollBarVisibility  of the ScrollViewer doesn't change. It's set to 'Auto' and if the ScrollBar is visible, the property is still auto.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using styles and triggers, like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=theScrollViewer, Path=ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <ScrollViewer Name="theScrollViewer">
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Comment: This is a clean approach however try to set BorderBrush as Transparent or BorderThickness to 0 instead of setting Border.Visibility since this code fragment right now will hide the entire Border and its children(the scrollviewer in it) when no scrollbar is needed.